# python: what is this funny notation? [0,1,3].__len__()

Tags: python

1. why would anyone use double underscores
2. why not just do `len([1,2,3])`?

my question is specifically **What do the *underscores* mean?**

Comment: This question, coming from a guy with two underscores in the user name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The one reason I've had to use `x.__len__()` rather than `len(x)` is due to the limitation that `len` can only return an `int`, whereas `__len__` can return anything.

You might quite reasonably argue that only an integer *should* be returned, but if the length of your object is greater than `sys.maxsize` then you have no choice except to return a `long` instead:

```
>>> class A(object):
...     def __len__(self):
...         return 2**80
...
>>> a = A()
>>> len(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OverflowError: long int too large to convert to int
>>> a.__len__()
1208925819614629174706176L
```

This isn't just a theoretical limitation, I've done a fair bit of work with bit containers where (with 32-bit Python) the `len` function stops working when the object reaches just 256MB.

Answer (score 4):

`__len__()` is the special Python method that is called when you use `len()`.

It's pretty much like `str()` uses `__str__()`, `repr` uses `__repr__()`, etc. You can overload it in your classes to give `len()` a custom behaviour when used on an instance of your class.

See here: [http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/ref/sequence-types.html](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/ref/sequence-types.htmlcontext.):

> `__len__(self)`
>   Called to implement the built-in function `len()`. Should return
>   the length of the object, an integer >= 0.
>   Also, an object that doesn't define a `__nonzero__()` method and
>   whose `__len__()` method returns zero is
>   considered to be false in a Boolean
>   context.

Comment: Fixed your formatting for you: you want backquotes to format as code, not backslashes to escape.

Answer (score 2):

If you "absolutely must" call it as a method (rather than a function) then the double underscores are needed.  But the only motivation I can think for the code you show of is that somebody's gone so OO-happy that they don't understand the key Python principle that you don't directly call special methods (except you may need to call your superclass's version if you're overriding it, of course) -- you use the appropriate builtin or operator, and *it* calls (internally) whatever special methods are needed.

Actually, in the code you show the only sensible thing is to just use the constant `3`, so maybe you've oversimplified your example a little...?-)

Answer (score 2):

You should read the docs on [special method names](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names).